# Quarkus native executable built on Windows not running inside a Docker container

Tags: docker, quarkus, quarkus-native

First, I build a `Quarkus native` image, everything seems to be fine. When I try to run it, I get the following error:

```
standard_init_linux.go:228: exec user process caused: no such file or directory
```

This is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:3.15

WORKDIR /deployment/

COPY native/*-runner /deployment/app

RUN chmod 775 /deployment

EXPOSE 8082
USER 1001

ENTRYPOINT [ "./app","-Dquarkus.http.host=0.0.0.0"]
```

I'm on a Windows machine and the command used to generate the native executable (the `*-runner` file) is:

```
mvn package -Pnative -Dquarkus.package.type=native -Dquarkus.native.container-build=true
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, after browsing similar issues, some were solved with the `-Dquarkus.native.container-build=true` flag, but it didn't work in my case. Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the Dockerfile, I was using `alpine:3.15` as base image.

After reading [the guide](https://quarkus.io/guides/building-native-image) again, this fixed the problem:

```
FROM quay.io/quarkus/quarkus-micro-image:1.0
```